# Get random item for array based on different probabilities?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, probability

Okay, imagine I'm creating a Pokemon game in JavaScript. I have an object like this...

```
pokemon = {
  "pikachu": {hp: 100, probability: 0.1},
  "squirtle": {hp: 90, probability: 0.2}
};
```

I basically need a function to select a pokemon in the object at random, but also based on the probability. So, in this case, the functions more likely to select a "squirtle" as it's probability is higher than "pikachu".

Comment: What do you need? A JavaScript function that returns a random number? I'm afraid you'll have to implement the logic yourself, as there are several ways of achieving what you want.

Comment: Is @Jean-Bernard Pellerin the best method to use?

Answer (score 7):

I would loop through the pokemon array and add up all of the probabilities. Call this `total`

Then generate a value between 0 and `total`. Call this `randVal`

Then loop through, adding up the probabilities again. Call this `secondTotal`
The first pokemon whose probability would push `secondTotal` above `randVal` is your selected pokemon.

Answer (score 3):

```
function pickAWinningItem(data) {
    var winner = Math.random();
    var threshold = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        threshold += parseFloat(data[i].prob);
        if (threshold > winner) {
            return data[i]

        }
    }
}
```

The sum of all probabilities must be equal to 1. With this function you stack the probabilities on top of each other and return the item, that the random number is the range of its probability.