# How to get a random element from an array of objects using probabilities in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, random

I try to call multiple times a method that draw an element from an array using probabilities.

My first method (first_function) is a promise that when resolved return this array :

```
[
  [
    {
      cardName: "Energy Fire",
      cardRatio: 50,
    },
    {
      cardName: "Energy Water",
      cardRatio: 50,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      cardName: "Charizard",
      cardRatio: 10,
    },
    {
      cardName: "Pikachu",
      cardRatio: 30,
    },
    {
      cardName: "Rayquaza",
      cardRatio: 60,
    },
  ],
];
```

When the promise is resolved, i call another method (second_function) :

```
my_promise.then((result) => {
  for (const position in result) {
    this.second_function(result[position]);
  }
});
```

There is my second method (second_function) :

```
function second_function(pull) {
  var winner = Math.random() * 100;
  var threshold = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < pull.length; i++) {
    threshold += pull[i].cardRatio;
    if (threshold > winner) {
      return console.log("winner", pull[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I want to draw a random card from each array (this is why i call multiple times second_function in the first_function) but the problem is just one draw is resolved (i see just one console.log). However, second_function is called multiple times like expected but it looks like the for loop in the second_function is called one time only.

Comment: maybe you should print the `winner`

Comment: in this case, the winner is just the random number choosed for the pull, the real winner result is ```pull[i]```

Comment: The term you're after is weight.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435183/generate-a-weighted-random-number

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks for the documentation, so my var "winner" is the weight.
Any ideas what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Yes. You're not normalizing weights. `100` should be a sum of weights in a group, or `threshold` should be divided by a sum. With your current implementation you'll likely need 2 loops to achieve that. Consider checking algos in the dupe question

Comment: I'm sorry i'm a little bit confused about what i need to do...
I check some other topics before coding my script and i found this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346112/get-random-item-for-array-based-on-different-probabilities
I used the same script than the answers, are they incorrect too ?